# How to Send Email using Service Broker?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

i am using Service Borker, wher i have Activated  stored procedure on TargetQueue. In this stored procedure i need to send a mail. But email is not going, when i see email logs its showing as below:

`DatabaseMail process is shutting down`

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in SQL Server Logs- sounds like there is error in code.
And i think its very possible that there is problem with user rights.